# pyqt5で簡単な画像処理をしたい

Tags: python, python3, pyqt

pyqt5で画像を等高線のように表示するGUIを作りたいです。画像を等高線のように表示するコードは次のように書けます。

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 画像読み込み
img = Image.open('300.png')
# グレースケール化
img = ImageOps.grayscale(img)
# ぼかし
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(3))
# 配列化
data = np.asarray(img)
# 等高線
plt.contour(data)
# 描画
plt.show()
```

これで、
[image: image1]
のような画像が
[image: image2]
このように変換されます。これを踏まえて、pyqt5を使ってGUIを書いたものが次のコードになります。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
import os.path
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas



class Example(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('実行',self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.calc)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        global img
        img = "300.png"
        self.button2.setIcon(QIcon(img))
        self.button2.setIconSize(QSize(400,300))

        layout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def calc(self):
        pass
        """
        image = Image.open(img)
        image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
        image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(3))
        data = np.asarray(image)
        plt.contour(data)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.axes.plot(data)

        self.button2.setIcon(self.canvas)
        """





if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

これで、次のようなGUIが出来ます。
[image: image3]
ここで、「実行」ボタンを押したときに表示されている画像が等高線表示されるようにしたいです。しかし、コードの４１行目のcalc関数の中をどのように書けばいいのか分かりません。グラフを画像データに変えることができればアイコンをその画像に置き換えることもできそうですが、画像データへの変換の仕方も分かりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

matplotlibの場合、画像データへの書き出しは、`fig.savefig()`でできるので、取り敢えず下のコードで動作します。

```
def calc(self):
    image = Image.open(img)
    image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
    image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(3))
    data = np.asarray(image)
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.contour(data)
    fig.savefig("fig.png")
    self.button2.setIcon(QIcon("fig.png"))
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。一度画像を保存してから改めて呼び出すんですね。

Comment: この件では直接Canvasに描画した方がベターだと思います。自分の場合は、Webメインでやっているので、Webでは画像は保存するしかないのでこういうやり方をしています。

Comment: そうですね。わかりやすい回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

以下のコードでは一度画像を保存することなく表示できます。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
import os.path
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas



class Example(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('実行',self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.calc)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        global img
        img = "300.png"
        self.button2.setIcon(QIcon(img))
        self.button2.setIconSize(QSize(400,300))

        layout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def calc(self):
        image = Image.open(img)
        image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
        image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(3))
        data = np.asarray(image)

        self.figure1 = plt.figure()
        self.axes1 = self.figure1.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure1)

        self.axes1.contour(data)
        self.canvas1.draw()

        size = self.canvas1.size()
        width, height = size.width(), size.height()
        im = QImage(self.canvas1.buffer_rgba(), width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)

        qim=QPixmap.fromImage(im)
        self.button2.setIcon(QIcon(qim))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```